# Importing the data constructor of an associated data type

Tags: haskell, ghc

I'm using GHC 7.10.2. There is a typeclass named `RenderRoute` in `yesod` that looks like this:

```
class Eq (Route a) => RenderRoute a where
  data Route a
  renderRoute :: Route a -> ([Text], [(Text, Text)])
```

I have written an instance in a module named `Yesod.Crud` that looks like this:

```
data Crud master p c = Crud { ... }
instance (PathPiece (Key c), Eq (Key c), PathPiece p, Eq p) => RenderRoute (Crud master p c) where
  data Route (Crud master p c)
    = EditR (Key c)
    | DeleteR (Key c)
    | IndexR p
    | AddR p
    | ViewR (Key c)
```

If, somewhere else, I import everything with like this

```
import Yesod.Crud
```

then the five data constructors belonging to my associated data type are in scope. I'm trying to figure out how to write the import statement in a more restrictive way. Let's say that I only want to bring `ViewR` into scope (and probably the data type `Crud` as well). If I try

```
import Yesod.Crud (ViewR)
```

Then GHC errors with the following:

```
src/Import/Base.hs:9:55:
    In module ‘Yesod.Crud’:
      ‘ViewR’ is a data constructor of ‘Route’
    To import it use
      ‘import’ Yesod.Crud( Route( ViewR ) )
    or
      ‘import’ Yesod.Crud( Route(..) )
```

If I try the first suggestion, it errors with

```
src/Import/Base.hs:10:46:
    Module ‘Yesod.Crud’ does not export ‘Route(ViewR)’
```

The second one is also wrong. But, the minor bug in GHC's error message suggestions is not what I'm interested in. What I would like to know is what the right way to do this is. I've already consulted [the manual](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/type-families.html), and I cannot discern a solution from the explanation of imports it offers.

Comment: I'm afraid this is just not possible. In general, importing of instances and anything associated with them can't be controlled cleanly. The idea being: a class immedately brings with it _all_ instances and associated types. But, prove me wrong – it certainly would make sense if this scenario were properly supported somehow.

Comment: @leftaroundabout, since Haskell modules are all about name control, being unable to import specific names is a serious mission failure.

Comment: I noticed that the data structures are being defined inside the instance declaration (the `data` keyword is right after the `where`)... Is there any particular reason for that? Could this be causing the errors?

Comment: Can you just re-export `Route` in `Yesod.Crud`?

Comment: @alexandrelucchesi That's how associated data families work. Everything works fine except for the `import` statement.

Comment: You haven't shown us how you're exporting stuff from your `Yesod.Crud` module. If you just have something like `module Yesod.Crud (RenderRoute(..)) where ...` then you won't be exporting the data constructors you want. But something like `module Yesod.Crud (RenderRoute(..), Route (..) ) where ...` looks like it is supposed to work, according to section 4.3.2 of the [manual](https://wiki.haskell.org/GHC/Type_families#Import_and_export) on type families. I haven't tried this myself btw, just throwing out a possible suggestion.